# Cannot render custom component in app.component.html

Tags: angular

I have created a custom component called `core.component` and imported it into a module of the same name.

**core.component.html**

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-left">
    <div class="row rows-cols-2 top-bar">
      <div>
        <h1>[Title]</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div>
        <h4>[Subtitle]</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="row align-baseline side-panel">
      <div class="col-3">
        <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Option 1</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Option 2</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**core.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-core',
  templateUrl: './core.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./core.component.scss']
})
export class CoreComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**core.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CoreComponent } from './core.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CoreComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

Finally, I import the core module into my root app module so that it is available for me to display it in the `<app-root>` element.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-core></app-core>
```

Unfortunately, instead of rendering the core component HTML, the compiler returns the following message, stating that it cannot recognize the component that I imported via the core module.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'app-core' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-core' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-core' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2 <app-core></app-core>
  ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "export" `CoreComponent` from *core.module.ts*:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CoreComponent } from './core.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CoreComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [CoreComponent],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cannot-render-custom-component-in-app-component-html-67xxp3)